# react form when i fill it out the form get send it self without any click on the button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-bootstrap

I'm working with bootstrap I don't know where the problem comes from but when I complete filling out the form it submits without any click on the button and it goes to de order cod database, and when I try to send it to the cp database by clicking on cp button nothing goes to the cp database

[image]

Comment: Try removing the "()" from `onOrderSubmitCOD`.

Comment: Please don't post images of code.